# Creating an instance of a pair

Tags: c++

This can be used to create an instance of a 2d vector of specific size:

```
#define rows 5
#define columns 7

std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2d(rows, std::vector<int>(columns));
```

What would be the equivalent for creating an instance of a pair that includes a size_t and a vector to be created with an initial size?

```
std::pair<size_t, std::vector<int>> psv(...(columns)...);
```

Thanks for the help, for a vector of these, this syntax seems to work.

```
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, std::vector<int>>>vpiv(rows,
    std::pair<size_t, std::vector<int>>(0, std::vector<int>(columns)));
```

Comment: Please stop `#define`ing container sizes.  There is absolutely no need for this in C++.  Just use an ordinary variable.  You can make it `const` or `constexpr` if you want.

Comment: Why would you want to store the initial size?

Comment: @jaymmer Hm it wasn't clear to me how the first value was related to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::pair<size_t, std::vector<int>> psv(my_size_t, std::vector<int>(my_vec_size));
```

Alternatively (Before C++11 `std::make_pair` could make some extra copies).

```
auto psv = std::make_pair(static_cast<size_t>(my_size_t), std::vector<int>(my_vec_size));
```

The cast is to ensure the first type is definitely `size_t`. It can be omitted if `my_size_t` is already of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

use [`std::make_pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/)

`std::make_pair(some_size, some_vector)`